# Why does Pale Moon fetch remote images when loading a "file:///" HTML page?

Tags: privacy, web-browser

When I order groceries, I get an e-mail receipt. I save this HTML file and save it.

Then I load it in Pale Moon some other time, so that its URL is `file:///C:/blablablabla/receipt.html`.

When I do this, it loads a bunch of images (logos and whatnot), hosted on Cloud-something. The point is, they are not images on my hard drive, but remote ones, so network requests are made for these images.

Shouldn't the fact that it is hosted on my hard disk and opened with the `file://` address/protocol/scheme mean that it blocks remote images? I don't want them to know that I look at my "offline receipt".

Is there some setting that controls this specifically? Why isn't it turned off by default? Seems like a massive security risk.

Comment: If you're using a browser to view emails, the browser probably has options to everything (both the HTML file and all the files it references). On Chrome these are "**Web Page, Complete**" and "**Web page, Single File**". (The first saves each resource in its own file; the second saves everything in one file). This will be closer to your expectations (and better for keeping copies of things like receipts). _If_ the HTML were to contain JavaScript, it _might_ still try to access the internet when you open it locally – you'd have to check.

Comment: @TripeHound I actually have automated the saving of the HTML receipts, so I don't have any such options. It's extracted from the actual e-mail.

Comment: @Bowserthebrowser: I don't know what can be done with Pale Moon to restrict network access. But for example with the Chromium browser you can set a proxy on the command line to something invalid (i.e. `--proxy-server="127.0.0.1:1"`) and this way you can prevent any network access.

Comment: Here, most assumptions and suspicions are false and using a browser that nobody knows is a problem itself since no one will research it or download to research it, at least not on a large scale.

Comment: What made you think that just because you load a HTML document via one scheme, it's not allowed to load resources from a different scheme? Do you have any sources that document such behaviour?

Comment: Short answer: because the file you saved included URIs to remote resources. Why should the program make the guess that you don't want it to follow the links in the file?

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** What you really want is a PDF of your receipt. HTML is intended for dynamic web content and is not going to do what you want. I suggest doing File > Print > As PDF instead.

---

You're expecting a web page to work the same way as a PDF or a Word doc where everything it needs is embedded inside it. That's just not how web pages work; HTML pages embed everything *by reference*. To borrow @SteffenUllrich's example, if you open your downloaded HTML document, you will probably notice a bunch of image tags of the form `<img src=http://example.com/foo.gif>`.

This behaviour of web pages is considered a good thing, for example if your browser has already seen `http://example.com/foo.gif` and you already have a copy of it on your hard drive (called "browser cache") then you can skip needing to download it again. Hurray for pages loading quickly! On the other hand, the linked content may be dynamic and the page designers want to reload it fresh each time in case it changed. Hurray for web pages being interactive!

---

As a test, I downloaded the main `security.stackexchange.com` page. Firefox's save dialog gave me the option of

[image: Firefox "Save page as" options]

If you select "HTML Only" then you're going to get the exact HTML page you were served, image references and all.

When I select "Web Page, Complete", I notice that I get the html page as well as a folder containing some of the referenced content -- js, css and image files

[image]

[image]

If I look at the html file, I notice that firefox has done some work to replace links to those files with local file links:

```
<img class="h-auto wmx100" src="(2)%20Information%20Security%20Stack%20Exchange_files/logo.svg" alt="Information Security">
```

but it hasn't done it consistently:

```
<img src=\"https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS5oO.png?s=32&amp;g=1\" alt=\"\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" class=\"bar-sm\">
```

and I'm not enough of an HTML expert to know why. Maybe because this one includes query params (`?s=32&amp;g=1`) firefox assumes that it's not static content and can't be cached? Or maybe as @ConorMancone suggests, this is a cross-domain reference (`stackexchange.com --> imgur.com`) and maybe firefox doesn't download cross-domain content when saving a page?

I think the point here is that firefox is *trying* to save the complete web page as you see it, but as web pages get more and more complex, the idea of "Save to file" doesn't really make sense. For example what does it mean to save a google maps page, or a Facebook Live stream? Firefox is trying its best here.

---

If you are looking to blame someone, you should ask your Pale Moon company to provide your receipts in PDF format since that's really what you're looking for. Alternatively, do File > Print > As PDF. Problem solved!

Comment: @Bowserthebrowser I don't know man. Reading your comments above with Steffen and Conor, you are the only one being angry and toxic. Saying *"Sorry man, but that's not how HTML works"* is not toxic IMO. If you can't ask questions anywhere without getting into fights ... maybe the problem is you?

Comment: @Bowserthebrowser I didn't see anything toxic or unfriendly, *au contraire*... Both Mike and Stephen are experts here, and both explained why you expected something that is not true. Bad wording perhaps (it happens), but both are trying to help, not being toxic and unfriendly. Asking questions and bashing the answers won't help you get knowledge.

Comment: For completeness, firefox may only download and save relative links.  More often then not the HREF is something like `/assets/whatever` or `//some/file`.  I expect it will download these.  If however the link is absolute then I wouldn't be *too* surprise if it saved it to the final HTML as an absolute link.  In particular, your example of a reference that didn't get changed is an image on imgur - this is obviously a separate domain and so it would have been referenced in the original HTML with an absolute ink rather than a relative.

Comment: Thanks @ConorMancone! I updated my answer.

Comment: @Bowserthebrowser - please read our [about] and [ask] ages, and once again read the posts people are making here to help you. You are the only one who is being at all toxic. So please look at your behaviour instead of blaming others for trying to help you, as we do not tolerate toxic behaviour here. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't the fact that it is hosted on my hard disk and opened with the file:// address/protocol/scheme mean that it blocks remote images?

That's not how HTML and browser work. It will load the images based on the URL's contained in the HTML page. Thus if it explicitly says `<img src=http://example.com/foo.gif>` it will do a HTTP request to example.com and load the image from there.

> Seems like a massive security risk.

The risk here is that you have the wrong expectations and acted based on these. Having the wrong expectations is not the fault of the browser.

Comment: @Bowserthebrowser The electronics store didn't give me the right change, so the next time I was there I picked up a game for the same amount of money and walked out the door without paying for it.  The security guard tackled me just outside of the doors.  This whole mess is clearly their fault.  My expectations were perfectly reasonable.

Comment: My point is, sometimes the issue really is just unrealistic expectations. It sounds like it didn't work the way you expected it to and you assume that the browser has made a critical security mistake.  Sometimes the answer is simple and your expectations were just wrong.  It happens.  Nothing Steffen said implied that he called you an idiot.